# perl csv not full number not displaying in cell

Tags: perl

Am generating the csv file, there is a problem in printing number on CELL,

Actual number is 1298271527197400000

but in my cell it display like 1.29827E+18

i dont want this shortcut , i want to show full number,

Comment: Is this actually a Microsoft Excel user interface question, rather than a Perl question?

Comment: How are you generating the CSV file? Are you using any CPAN module? How are you displaying the CSV file? Excel? Notepad? vi?

Comment: Forgetting about how it displays in a spreadsheet app for a moment, does the number appear correct in the actual CSV output?

Comment: If you are doing data analysis (science perhaps?, 1e18 is a large number for day-to-day operations) and not really as a spreadsheet, may I recommend much nicer open source programs such as QtiPlot or the fork of that called SciDAVis. http://scidavis.sourceforge.net/ They has easy options to change things like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using the popular and excellent `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` module from CPAN (you didn't actually specify), you'll need to specify a `format` for the cell, similar to the following:

```
  my $fmt = $workbook->add_format( num_format => '0' );
  $worksheet->write_string( 'A2', 1298271527197400000, $fmt );
```

More information here:

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#FORMAT_METHODS

and you can get a sample by running the module's `examples/formats.pl` script, which outputs a demo workbook called `formats.xls`, that shows you the various formats on your system.

Note: It may still appear in the top bar in scientific notation, but if you adjust the column width to fit the number, it displays in the actual cell in standard decimal format.

---

Since I clearly need more coffee: You can use the above module to directly generate a well-formatted spreadsheet for Excel, in addition to providing a CSV output option for other tools.

Comment: Going by the question, he's just producing CSV which he's  then opening in a speadsheet app, not writing an Excel worksheet.

Comment: *facepalm*  Thanks.  Looks like I picked the wrong week to quit sniffing glue!

Comment: Hehe, +1 for the reference :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Excel, right-click the cell, click the "Cell formatting" entry (or whatever looks closest to that), find the number formats, and look around for an entry that doesn't use scientific or engineering formats.

Comment: While this might work some times, in some versions of Excel it will discard "insignificant" portions of the number when it's imported leaving a number that is different than the original.

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening your CSV file in Excel the only safe way to load a large number is to treat it as text *as it is imported*.
To do this change the file extension to .txt, and then select the file in Excel's open dialog. This will start the text import wizard.

- On step 1 pick Delimited.
- On step 2 pick only Comma as the Delimiter and " as Text Qualifier.
- On step 3 pick the column containing the large number and select Text as the data format.

All this is based on Excel 2003, other versions will almost certainly be different.